# Comparisons between time, wanting to create a small actions restriction for some players

Tags: java

I'm developing a game, and I want to restrict some player's actions for one hour when they are 'new' (playtime less than one hour), the timer should start when they create account, and after that one hour has elapsed, the restriction is should be over.

I got a small version of it working, but It had a problem, it was counting even when player was offline, so I added a `LocalDate currentTime` and made it count every tick rate.

But now I am struggling to compare how long it has been elapsed and I can't finish the code, can someone help me with the logics?

This is the actual code:

```java
package com.rs.game.player;

import com.rs.utils.Utils;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalTime;

public class AccountRestriction implements Serializable {
    public enum RestrictionType {
        TRADING,DROPPING_ITEMS,PVP
    }

    private transient Player player;

    LocalTime startedTime;

    LocalTime currentTime;

    LocalTime finishTime;

    public void setPlayer(Player player) {
        this.player = player;
    }

    /**
     * Counts what time is the player at every tick (600ms)
     */
    public void count() {
        Duration currentTimeRelatedToNow = Duration.between(startedTime, LocalTime.now());

        currentTime.minus(currentTimeRelatedToNow);

        System.out.println("count(currentTime="+currentTime.toString()+")");
    }

    /**
     * Stops the restriction counter when a player logout
     */
    public void logout() {
        Duration timeLapsed = Duration.between(startedTime, LocalTime.now());

        this.currentTime = currentTime.minus(timeLapsed);
    }
    /**
     * The object
     * @param player The player
     */
    public AccountRestriction(Player player) {
        this.player = player;
        this.startedTime = LocalTime.now();
        this.currentTime = startedTime;
        this.finishTime = startedTime.plusHours(1); //plusHours 1
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return Get when we started.
     */
    public LocalTime getStartedTime() {
        return startedTime;
    }

    public LocalTime getCurrentTime() {
        return currentTime;
    }

    /**
     * Checks if account is restricted
     * @return {@code true} if restricted, {@code false} if not
     */
    public boolean isRestricted(RestrictionType type) {
        //LocalTime now = LocalTime.now();


        if (currentTime.compareTo(finishTime) >= 0) {
            System.out.println("");
            return false;
        } else {
            player.sm(getRestriction(type));
            return true;
        }

        /*if (now.compareTo(finishTime) >= 0)
            return false;
         else {
             player.sm(getRestriction(type));
            return true;
        }*/
    }


    /**
     * Gets the restriction message
     * @param type The type The type
     * @return The string representation for the restriction
     */
    public String getRestriction(RestrictionType type) {
        long timeLeft = Duration.between(LocalTime.now(), finishTime).toMinutes();

        return "You are restricted for <col=ff0000>" +(timeLeft == 60 ? "1</col> hour!" : (timeLeft == 1 ? "</col>a minute" : timeLeft < 1 ? " less than a minute</col>" : timeLeft+"</col> minutes!") + "</col>, and can't access: <col=ff0000>"+ Utils.formatPlayerNameForDisplay(type.name()+"</col>!"));
    }
}
```

My issue is in method `isRestricted()` as I'm missing the logics to check if the player has a gametime greater than one hour before doing the actions I want

Comment: Would recommend just using some integers to track Hours, Minutes, and Seconds played. At the start of game launch get the time, then every tick or so do a current time minus start time and check against or update the Hours, Minutes, and Seconds variables based on this. Then just store those tracking integers for loading next launch when saving/closing the game.

Comment: Even simpler, count the number of ticks. If a tick is coming every 600 ms, then once they reach 6,000 ticks, they've played for an hour.